# How to set default role in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, users

I have created some user roles in my drupal 6 website.

Have can set one of them as default role when users register in the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Auto Assign Role](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) module will allow this.

It allows you to:

1. Provide an automatic assignment of roles when a new account is created.
2. Allow the end user to choose their own role or roles when they create their account.
3. Provide paths that will trigger a specific role when an account is created.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [Registration role](http://drupal.org/project/registration_role) module.

Registration role lets an administrator select a role to automatically assign to new users. The selected role will be assigned to new registrants.